# npm install using pre-release versions

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

i want to use pre-release versions in my package.json to get some dependencies in the latest version (containing als pre-releases) but for some reasons it doesn't work in my case. The pre-releases are fully ignored. As an example lets use angular. If I ask `"angular": ">=1.4.0-rc.0 <1.4.1"` as an dependency, i would expect that i would get the version `1.4.0-rc.2` installed, but i get just the version `1.4.0`.

The `npm info angular` shows, that there are some rc versions available like

> ...
>   '1.4.0-beta.4',
>   '1.4.0-beta.5',
>   '1.4.0-beta.6',
>   '1.4.0-rc.0',
>   '1.4.0-rc.1',
>   '1.4.0-rc.2',

My package.json looks as follows right now

```
"dependencies": {
   "angular": ">=1.4.0-rc.0 <1.4.1"
}
```

Any ideas why i dont get any rc versions? What do i have to do to get it working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seems logical, the order of versions is normally the following (for angular releases 1.4.x):

1. **1.4.0-beta.0**
2. **1.4.0-beta.2**
3. **1.4.0-beta.3**
4. **1.4.0-beta.4**
5. **1.4.0-beta.5**
6. **1.4.0-beta.6**
7. **1.4.0-rc.0**
8. **1.4.0-rc.1**
9. **1.4.0-rc.2**
10. **1.4.0**
11. **1.4.1**

If you request `"angular": ">=1.4.0-rc.0 <1.4.1"`, The latest version that is less strictly 1.4.1 is **1.4.0**

Anyway, if you demand `"angular": ">=1.4.0-rc.0 <1.4.0"`, the latest version will be **1.4.0-rc.2**

Comment: Yes you are right, i've realized the same several minutes ago ... at the beginning its somehow confusing, but when really thinking about it, it's obvious :-)